# How to printf line in java

Tags: java

Hello I'm new in java and I have an assignment to printf a line. I think it is `printf line` in java but I'm only familiar with assembly and C++ advanced editions. How should I go about printing a line in Java??

Comment: What are "assembly and C++ advanced editions"? :-|

Answer (score 2):

System.out.printf(...)
[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

Comment: hello thanks for the quick reply senor however i am getting syntax error

Comment: printf() only became available in Java 1.5 so make sure that you're not running an older (pre-2004) version.

Comment: System.out.format() does the same thing, and is generally used in standard documentation / tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 42;
        System.out.printf("life universe and everything = %d%n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I see that prints the string of the life uni. but Im just printing a "f" line is it printf or println according to my teacher

Comment: You didn't really mean `%n` at the end, did you?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, yes I do mean '%n'.

Comment: @Steven I'm not sure what you mean by 'printing a "f" line', I was assuming you meant printing a formatted string.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about it, found it in the Formatter docs though. Nice!